# How i give Space After each property Name form foreach loop

Tags: model-view-controller

@foreach (var sub in Model.SubjectSubscriptions)
        {

```
        @Html.DisplayFor( m => sub.Subjects.Name)

    }
```

I have to give a space or comma after each name

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var sub in Model.SubjectSubscriptions) {
    sub.Subjects.Name += ", ";

    ...

}
```